# Python's ImportError: No module named repository

Tags: python, repository, python-2.7, python3

I had three versions of Python installed; 2.7, 3.2 and 3.4 When I had just 2.7 and 3.2, everything was fine. But after installing 3.4 manually from source, things began to break down. 3.4 did not have `gi` so I installed it via `pip3` and it went fine.

After installing 3.4 and "gi", repository went missing from 2.7 (it was working before I installed 3.4):

```
>>> import gi.repository
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named repository
```

So I re-installed `python-gi` and `repository` still is missing. So in urge, I manually removed python 3.2 and 3.4 simply by deleting the binaries from `/usr/local` and also removing the default directories where they were installed. The problem still persists. Again, note that python found `repository` finely before the installation of 3.4.

Any fix, please?

Comment: now you are in trouble. Python3.4 package cannot be removed clean. It's broken now.

Comment: use `dpkg -l | grep python-gi` to check if you installed gi for python2.x

Answer (score 1):

I must admit one thing: I like to toy with python a lot, because I use python a lot, and as a consequence (as we are human) our toying can break things.

So I came to this problem by simply wanting to install new piece of software on my Ubuntu (14.04 probably irrelevant for this cause). I start 'Ubunty Software Center' and nothing happens.

Upon an investigation as to where this piece starts I learn it can be called from the command line as:

```
$ software-center
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 25, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
ImportError: No module named repository
```

Gee. I am in similar shoes as you are. How the heck I endup in this situation to break a system tool? Of course needless to say that I have numerous different python (both 2 and 3 and then some other) installations so what software center expects to run?

```
$ more /usr/bin/software-center
#! /usr/bin/python
# Copyright (C) 2009-2011 Canonical
#
# Authors:
#  Michael Vogt
la la la...
```

ok it is `/usr/bin/python` then. Let's see:

```
$ /usr/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

to be honest I expected some lower version, but this is fine (hopefully). So why I cannot find gi.repository?

```
$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jan  9 2017, 12:16:27) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gi.repository
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named repository
>>> import gi
>>> import gi.repository
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named repository
```

Gi loads, but has no repository. This is the puzzle that took me around many questions and answers on stack overflow. Lot of hints here and there, installed this, installed that, tried this & that, including reinstalling modules even default python using apt-get and reinstalling left and right this and that module. But the problem was stubborn, it kept insisting on not finding the repository no matter what I have tried of various recipes in different answers.

In short - **NOTHING of that WORKED**.

I took a break to think how to approach the problem. After a while I come to a question:

How do I know which library I am actually loading? Import in Python is very well (however somewhat superficially) documented. It lacks deeper documentation that can actually help you to hack around. Was contemplating to fix the issue via PYTHONPATH. But then...

By stroke of luck I find following fine piece of writing. Cannot thank enough for this article as it gave essential hints where to look for the problem. Read it carefully!

https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html

Lee, you are my hero!

Following hints from Lee's article I look into which paths are examined:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi-1.2-py2.7.egg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
... la la la ...
```

hey, what the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi-1.2-py2.7.egg` does in this list? Aren't it supposed to load libraries from `/usr/lib/python2.7/` not `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/` that's totally different Python installation and version ?!?! I must have messed something at some stage.

Knowing from other hints that 'gi' is not normally installed via pip (but via `apt-get install python-gi`) and I remember that among other things I have installed gi in order to solve this problem (which was unsucessful at a time). Its not that reading of other hints and ideas did not help - they added nibbles here and there and shed some light to a problem.

I had an idea: What if I simply deinstall that 'gi'. Perhaps paths would come back to normal. However I have to make sure that I am hitting right pip (not one from command line). To ensure that (exit() from python) run pip module instead of pip itself (what does pip do to find things? this is still unanswered.)

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/python -m pip uninstall gi
Uninstalling gi:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi-1.2-py2.7.egg
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled gi
```

Nice. Even if python tries to load gi, it will not find it in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`

as a result:

```
$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jan  9 2017, 12:16:27) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode
```

How nice :). Lets try now:

```
$ software-center
```

Voila! It's working!!! Yeee!!!

Now, moral of the story:

**It is not always what you did not install (because you believe its missing), but something that you have installed extra and it shall be better to be removed.**

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Python 3 versions of the packages.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-gi
```